# Excel Interop: Creating instance with Task.Run results in exception System.EntryPointNotFoundException

Tags: c#, task, excel-interop

Here is my minimal example producing the problem:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();

            if (app != null)
            {
                app.Quit();
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(app);
                app = null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This results in the following exception:

[image]

The last part in Japanese says the `"EventSetInformation" of DLL advapi32.dll entry point cannot be found`.
I'm having difficulty understanding what is going on. Basically why is this exception being thrown and what it is trying to tell me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception in my example was produced with VS 2013 on Windows 7.
In this case, the call to `EventSetInformation` could not be resolved as the function could not be found in `advapi32.dll`.
Then, I tested the same code with Visual Studio 2015 CTP and it ran to completion without any exceptions. This led me to believe it was a version conflict.

Also, according to [here](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/dump/win7_vs_win8/export%20lists/advapi32.dll.html) and [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447256%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `EventSetInformation` was **added** to advapi32.dll in Windows 8. This is why it could not be found when I ran the code with VS 2013. Therefore, to run my code snippet, I needed the newer version of advapi32.dll which is included with later Visual Studio versions (or Windows 8).

**UPDATE**

According to https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/974

> Note that the OS group has assured us that Win7 will be patched to
>   include this API soon (within months), so that even the exception will
>   not happen at that point

So, most likely advapi32.dll on Windows 7 will be updated to include `EventSetInformation` some time in the future.